# Goldbach for certain classes of $n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbachs-conjecture

The [Wiki article on the Goldbach conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach's_conjecture) *(where $\#$ of ways even $n$ can be represented by prime additions is heareafter denoted $G(n)$)* states that

> In 1975, Hugh Montgomery and Robert Charles Vaughan showed that "most" even numbers were expressible as the sum of two primes. More precisely, they showed that there exist positive constants $c$ and $C$ such that for all sufficiently large numbers N, every even number less than N is the sum of two primes, with at most $C N^{1-c}$ exceptions. In particular, the set of even integers which are not the sum of two primes has density zero.

Has the Goldbach conjecture been proven for any *specific* classes on $n$? By exhautive search,it has been proven for $4\leq n \leq 10^{18},$ but my question is whether it has been proven for *eg* primorial multiples, where $G(n)$ generally reaches it's maximum. Surely it is not difficult to prove for the primorials, or am I mistaken as to the sheer complexity of the task?

**Reposted to MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224411/goldbach-for-certain-classes-of-n)**

Comment: Wait, what did you define as $G(n)$? I thought it referenced the conjecture;s truth for $n$, or maybe the wikipedia page. How can it have a maximum?

Comment: $G(n)=\#$ ways even $n$ can be represented by prime additions.

Comment: Why should the proof be easy for primorials ?

Comment: @Peter I realise probabilistic arguments are difficult to make rigorous, but for the primorials, they are of course the most likely to have multiple additive prime partitions.

Comment: By the way, do we know a (conditional or not) lower bound for $c$?

Comment: @SylvainJulien If I were to guess, I'd say not, but then that's just a guess. I don't have a copy of *Multiplicative number theory* handy, but I should think it would be be a good place to look.

Answer (score 0):

The upper limit for G(n), n=2m, with m odd is: $$\pi(m)-\omega(m)-1$$ This is reached by 30, as 15 has 6 primes less than it, 1 of which is 2 which Goldbach ignores, and 2 are distinct prime factors of 15 (and hence 30), which can't participate as distributivity of multiplication over addition of negatives (subtraction for numbers) shows. 
 That forces p to divide or be divisible by q in p+q=2m. The others below 15 lead to Goldbach partitions of 30, 7+23=11+19=13+17=30 . But, NO this doesn't prove it for primorials.